Cannot upgrade from Ubuntu 23.10 or 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04
The new Ubuntu 24.04 has been release but I can't upgrade the system using the update manager, because nothing appears. I have Ubuntu 23.10. I tried to change to long term releases and back to any version to no avail.
I don't know what I can do to upgrade beside installing again.
Is there a command I can use upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 from Ubuntu 23.10 ?

conventional wisdom suggests upgrading after the first point release which in this case will be this summer (around August) is the best plan. Don't be too hasty - you might live to regret it if you read some of the questions rainsed here over the past few days...

Are you asking this question every 6 months?

Does this answer your question? Why is "No new release found" when upgrading from a LTS to the next?

Don't try to upgrade the day Ubuntu 24.04 is released
Some upgrade bugs are still getting ironed out
See this post for details: Why You Shouldn’t Upgrade to Ubuntu 24.04 LTS Yet
Just wait a week or two. Eventually when you open the Software Updater app, it will prompt you to upgrade. Big upgrades like this are rolled out in stages, so that everyone does not try to upgrade at the same time and overload and crash the download servers.
For upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04
The wait is not over yet. LTS release upgrade prompt won't appear until a few weeks after the version 24.04.1 is released in August 2024.
Hope this helps

The wait for non-LTS users is over, see end of https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release

From the Ubuntu 24.04 Release Notes:

Upgrades
Users of Ubuntu 23.10 will be offered an automatic upgrade to 24.04 soon after the release.
Users of 22.04 LTS however will be offered the automatic upgrade when 24.04.1 LTS is released, which is scheduled for the 15th of August.

"Soon after the release" typically does not mean a day or two. Historically, it has meant several weeks.

It will be offered to 23.10 users when it has been tested and is ready. When the Ubuntu Release Team decides upon a date, they will announce it.
It will be offered to 22.04 LTS users around 15 August 2024.

Non-LTS users are sometimes surprised by this LTS-specific delay in relase-upgrades. The much larger numbers of LTS users has led to a phased rollout of LTS releases so that the community and developers can offer the best support as inevitable problems are discovered.

(This windows is now closed:) Impatient folks can experiment with a release-upgrade by using do-release-upgrade -d, which still works for a week or two until the next development release repositories are set up. However, be warned that it might fail. You may encounter unexpected behavior. Your system may become unbootable. You may lose data. The use of -d means "I want to be a tester" and that you are willing to accept risk.


where i can see when its going to be avaiable

Link to the Release Team schedule added.

@Tiago Earth Don't you do daily updates at closedown every day ? If you do, it'll be here when it's here . . .

If it's stable to upgrade, it will appear here: https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release ;
So right now, it's only available in Dev: https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-development ;

If you don't want to wait till August 2024 to upgrade to 24.04 and are ok with encountering some bugs following guide can help you.
https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-upgrade-from-ubuntu-22-04-lts-to-ubuntu-24-04-lts/
There is a two step path to upgrade.
First upgrade to 23.10.
Then upgrade form 23.10 to 24.04.

Are you getting this error?

There is no development version of an LTS available.
To upgrade to the latest non-LTS development release set Prompt=normal in
/etc/update-manager/release-upgrades.


There are multiple ways to upgrade Ubuntu 22.04 LTS before the release of 24.04.1 LTS, scheduled for August 15th, 2024. Here’s one safe method:
Edit the /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades file and set Prompt=normal
Run:
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
Set:
Prompt=normal
Save and close the file.
Next, run:
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
Follow all onscreen instructions. This will get you 23.10 release and reboot the system.
Run:
sudo reboot
Then, again edit the /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades and set Prompt=lts
Type:
sudo nano /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
Set:
Prompt=lts
Save and close the file.
Finally, type the following command and follow the rest of the guide to upgrade from 23.10 to 24.04 LTS:
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
This note will automatically disappear after August 15th, 2024, as there will be no need for this kind of workaround. As a seasoned sysadmin and developer, I recommend waiting until the release of 24.04.1 LTS (scheduled for August 15th, 2024) before upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. This ensures superb stability and minimizes potential compatibility issues with your apps. However, you can use these instructions for testing purposes. This is a great way to check if your applications will work seamlessly with Ubuntu 24.04 LTS.

Great answer for anyone who is totally pressed to jump to 24.04 but 24.04.1 LTS has been moved to August 29, 2024. That's a two weeks delay from the initial August 15, 2024 date.

Above answer suggests upgrade to 23.04 first, and then 24.04, however, there still have method to upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 direct.
The upgrade program will check website record in /etc/update-manager/meta-release, in which, the ubuntu 24.04 is marked as supported: 0 logically, you may enable it by point to a custom modify file.
Below an example to use a temporary local server to do this replace.

mkdir /tmp/fake-ubuntu-release-meta
cd /tmp/fake-ubuntu-release-meta

create a modified meta-release file


cat <<EOF >meta-release-lts
Dist: jammy
Name: Jammy Jellyfish
Version: 22.04.3 LTS
Date: Thu, 21 April 2022 22:04:00 UTC
Supported: 1
Description: This is the 22.04.3 LTS release
Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
ReleaseNotesHtml: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/jammy.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy-updates/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/jammy.tar.gz.gpg


Dist: noble
Name: Noble Numbat
Version: 24.04 LTS
Date: Thu, 25 April 2024 24:04:00 UTC
Supported: 1
Description: This is the 24.04 LTS release
Release-File: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/Release
ReleaseNotes: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement
ReleaseNotesHtml: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/ReleaseAnnouncement.html
UpgradeTool: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/noble.tar.gz
UpgradeToolSignature: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/main/dist-upgrader-all/current/noble.tar.gz.gpg
EOF


vim meta-release-lts -c "set ff=unix" -c ":wq"
Convert it's line feed to unix style, instead of windows style

python -m http.server
Start a small web server locally for the file above

Open a new terminal, edit /etc/update-manager/meta-release, change it to


[METARELEASE]
# original
#URI = https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
#URI_LTS = https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts

# modify
URI_LTS = http://127.0.0.1:8000/meta-release-lts

URI_UNSTABLE_POSTFIX = -development
URI_PROPOSED_POSTFIX = -proposed


In the new terminal, run
do-release-upgrade

Boom! Now just go through the normal upgrade process.

Dont forget to recover the file content after upgrade.


Warning: This method is a temporary solution, it shall not be needed after the 24.04 upgrade become GA.

############################# TO UPGRADE OVDER VERSION #######################################
make a copy of your repo list file
cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/OLDsources.list
#edit the sources.list file with your favourite editor
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
Get latest repo list for your version from: https://www.veeble.com/kb/sources-list-file-urls-ubuntu/ and replace
Then replace all URLs with http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu   leaving the part after the word ubuntu as is
E.g
'http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates Release'
shall become
'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu mantic-updates Release'
Save and close /etc/apt/sources.list
Then use the following command in sequence
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
sudo apt dist-upgrade -y
sudo apt install update-manager-core -y
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
sudo apt autoremove -y
sudo apt autoclean
lsb_release -a
##############################################################################################
